# Choose Combobox item with Pywinauto

Tags: python, automation, window, pywinauto

I've programmed a script to automate some activities. [The figure 1 shows the window that I face some problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFOfJ.png), specifically  the "Locomotora" drop down menu. 
The information is in Spanish, however It isn't a problem to the error description.

The current implementation receives 2 entry parameters:

- Locomotora item position: position of the item selected in the drop down menu "Locomotora".
- number of messages: how many times "Enviar" will
  be pressed, sending messages with data filled.

The code below it is the current script that I developed.

With control_identifiers method, in the while loop, [returned value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUjKH.png), I've discovered that the menu can be controlled with libreComboBox2.

```
from pywinauto import application
import sys, time

def send_message(repeat_number,locomotora,content):
    app = application.Application().connect(path ="C:\APP\app.exe")

    command = "%HQ{{DOWN {} }}".format(locomotora)
    iterCounter = 0

    while (iterCounter < repeat_number):
        try:
        #Get window focused
            tfrmenviarmacrolivredlg = app.top_window()
            tfrmenviarmacrolivredlg.SetFocus()

        #print window control identifiers
            tfrmenviarmacrolivredlg.print_control_identifiers()

        # Choose locomotora 
            tfrmenviarmacrolivredlg.libreComboBox2.type_keys(command)

        #Set text content
            tfrmenviarmacrolivredlg['Edit'].set_text(content)

        #Send(Enviar) Message
            tfrmenviarmacrolivredlg['Enviar'].click()
            time.sleep(1)

            iterCounter += 1

        except IOError as e:
           print("I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
        except ValueError as v:
           print("Could not convert data to an integer.".format(v.errno, v.strerror))
        except Exception as ex:
           print("Unexpected error:".format(ex.errno, ex.strerror))
           sys.exc_info()[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print("Not enough arguments")
        print("python3 send_message_pywinauto.py [number_of_messages] [locomotora] ")
        exit(1)

    n_rows = int(sys.argv[1])

    locomotora_item_position  = int(sys.argv[2])
    send_message(n_rows,locomotora_item_position,"0123456789"*30)
```

It works, but to choose an item from the "Locomotora" drop down menu the script "types" {DOWN} until reach the item position ( tfrmenviarmacrolivredlg.libreComboBox2.type_keys(command) ).

The appropriate execution must use "select" method to choose the "locomotora" in the drop down.

I tried the following command, but it didn't work:

```
tfrmenviarmacrolivredlg.libreComboBox2.select("locomotora_name")
```

[Command result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaIb1.png)

How can I select the item with its name?

Comment: What does `tfrmenviarmacrolivredlg.libreComboBox2.item_texts()` return?

Comment: Maybe `.expand().collapse()` will help to initialize the drop down list of the combo box?

Comment: Answering the first question, nothing, tfrmenviarmacrolivredlg.libreComboBox2.item_texts() returns nothing.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I've tried ".expand().collapse()", but the terminal result was:


"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Program\Python\Python38-2\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 180, in __call__ raise AttributeError("Neither GUI element (wrapper)" \
AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'expand' were found (typo?)

Comment: OK, let’s try Application(backend=“uia”) then.

Comment: I believe that the application does not support "uia" accessibility technology, because the commands that normally executes with Application() set to default value didn't run with Application("uia"). 

I also tried to execute ".print_control_identifiers()" method, but it didn't return anything either.

Comment: "uia" technology has wider coverage than "win32" in any case. Or at least the same coverage at a minimum. But the hierarchy of elements is different. So the commands may be different as well.